# Getting an array from string.split() java

Tags: java, arrays

so I have the following bit of code:

```
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] row = line.split(",");
    this.table.add(row);
```

Where this.table was initiated using:

```
ArrayList table = new ArrayList();
```

Then when I tried to get the length a row in table like so:

```
for(int i=0; i<table.size(); ++i){
    for(int j=0; j<table.get(i).length; ++j) {
        //some code    
        }
```

It (underlines get(i).length; and gives me an error saying that it cannot find symbol. symbol: length location: class Object.

What's wrong? Does string.split() not return an array? If it does, why can I not use any of the array class methods / variables?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ArrayList is not a List of Arrays, it's a list *backed by* an array.

But you can make it a List of arrays by using generics.

```
List<String[]> table = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

Then your code should work.

Comment: Thank you. Do I need to import anything to use List? Because it tells me it cannot find symbol?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [java generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)

```
List<String[]> table = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

Then you would get `String[]` instances with the `get(i)` calls. Also note using the `List` interface to declare the table variable. Wheever possible, use the superinterface that suits your needs, and not the implementation class.

Also, starting from Java 1.5, you can use the much more intuitive for syntax (of course, this assumes that you use the generics recommended before):

```
for(String[] processedRow : table){
    for(String processedField : processedRow) {
        //some code    
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. I tried doing that for loop and it would give me that error so I figured I was implementing the loop wrong. But apparently not :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to type your list:

```
List<String[]> table = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

then the java compiler will know the `String[]` are stored in your list.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList table = new ArrayList();
//  change with:
ArrayList<String[]> table = new ArrayList();
```